# Parse dates with any separator using python's strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm parsing a date using Python's `datetime.strptime`.  The dates are in `%Y/%m/%d` format, but I want to be agnostic about the separator used for the dates - `/`, `-`, `.` and any others are all fine.

Right now, I'm using a `try` block, but it's a bit verbose.

Is there a simple way to accept any given separator for `strptime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to use a regular expression to normalize the separators:

```
import re

datetimestring = re.sub('[-.:]', '/', datetimestring)
```

would replace any `-`, `.` or `:` character with a slash.

Alternatively, use the [`dateutil.parser.parse()` function](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) to handle arbitrary date-time formats; it is extremely flexible towards separators.

Comment: If it matters, this allows a date string like `2001-2.21`

Comment: True, I'm being really aggressive and using `re.sub('[^0-9]', '/', datestring)` - anything other than a number is a separator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named groups and a named back-reference:

```
import re, datetime

txt='''\
1994-8-22
1970 1 1
2014/01/03
2000.1.1
1999 8 27
1991/02-01   bad date'''

for test in txt.splitlines():
    dt=re.match(r'\s*(?P<Y>\d\d\d\d)(?P<sep>\D)(?P<m>\d\d?)(?P=sep)(?P<d>\d\d?)', test)
    if dt:
        print '"{:10}"=>{:20}=>{}'.format(test, 
                                      dt.group(*'Ymd'),
                                      datetime.date(*map(int, dt.group(*'Ymd'))))
```

That allows you to make sure that the separators are flexible (any non digit) but consistent. ie, this is a good date: `1999/1/2` but this `1999-1/2` maybe is not.

Prints:

```
"1994-8-22 "=>('1994', '8', '22') =>1994-08-22
"1970 1 1  "=>('1970', '1', '1')  =>1970-01-01
"2014/01/03"=>('2014', '01', '03')=>2014-01-03
"2000.1.1  "=>('2000', '1', '1')  =>2000-01-01
"1999 8 27 "=>('1999', '8', '27') =>1999-08-27
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to not use strptime, and do something like:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(*map(int, re.findall('\d+', your_string)))
```

Although your forgo some validation there - such as if there's more than three fields, they'll become arguments to `datetime` instead of raising an exception that there's unparsed string.

Answer (score 0):

```
from dateutil import parser

Answer = parser.parse(yourtimestring)
```